# After migration Oracle to SQL, sysdb does not exist

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I performed a migration from Oracle to Sql Server 2012 whith SSMA (SQL Server Migration Assistant) and then when I run my application, I get the following error: 
-SQL error: database 'sysdb' does not exist. make sure that the name is entered correctly.

On this post, Lalit gives the the following information but without solution: [Issue in deploying DB project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939380/issue-in-deploying-db-project)

1. Should I install the SSMA tool extension?
2. Should I create the sysdb?

Can you please help me to find a structural solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034831/after-performing-oracle-to-sql-server-migration-i-lost-my-sysdb-database-how-ca

Comment: I have installed the ssma extension packed but problem is not solved. Should I migrate all data again?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions and install it on the box with SQL Server?  sysdb should be created upon installation.

Comment: I didn't have permission to install it so the customer installed it himself but I have access to the sql instance. 
Where can I check that the sysdb is created?